# Slicing by start and stop string values in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string in which there are certain values that I need to extract from it. For example: `"FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDC"`. How could I make an expression that would take a slice from `"START"` all the way to `"END"`?

I tried doing this previously by creating functions which used a `for` loop and `string.find("START")` to locate the beginning and ends, but this didn't appear to work effectively and seemed overly complex. Is there an easier way to do this without using complex loops?

---

**EDIT**:

Forgot this part. What if there were different end values? In other words, instead of just ending with `"END"`, the values `"DONE"` and `"NOMORE"` would also end it? And in addition to that, there were multiple starts and ends throughout the string. For example: `"STARTFFEFFDONEFEWFSTARTFEFFENDDDW"`.

EDIT2: Sample run: Start value: ATG. End values: TAG,TAA,TGA

```
"Enter a string": TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT
TTT
GGGCGT
```

And

```
"Enter a string": TGTGTGTATAT
"No string found"
```

Comment: In your second case, what if both `"DONE"` *and* `"END"` are present, e.g. `STARTabcDONEdefEND"`? What if there are overlaps, e.g. `"STARTabsSTARTdefENDghiEND"`? You need to be clear about the "rules" you are operating under.

Comment: I think it would help to show examples of your input and expected output.

Comment: Hmm, I was suspecting that you were going to try and match start and stop codons...but if that's what you're after, you need to make sure to always match triplets. Otherwise, `ATGATAGCCTAG` would only match `ATGATAG` which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a perfect fit for a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDCSTARTDOINVOIJHSDFDONEDFOIER"
>>> re.findall("START.*?(?:END|DONE|NOMORE)", s)
['STARTFFFPEND', 'STARTDOINVOIJHSDFDONE']
```

`.*` matches any number of characters (except newlines), the additional `?` makes the quantifier lazy, telling it to match as few characters as possible. Otherwise, there would be only one match, namely `STARTFFFPENDDCDCSTARTDOINVOIJHSDFDONE`.

As @BurhanKhalid noted, if you add a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), only the substring matched by that part of the regex will be captured:

```
>>> re.findall("START(.*?)(?:END|DONE|NOMORE)", s)
['FFFP', 'DOINVOIJHSDF']
```

**Explanation:**

```
START    # Match "START"
(        # Match and capture in group number 1:
 .*?     # Any character, any number of times, as few as possible
)        # End of capturing group 1
(?:      # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
 END     # "END"
|        # or
 DONE    # "DONE"
|        # or
 NOMORE  # "NOMORE"
)        # End of non-capturing group
```

And if your real goal is to match gene sequences, you need to make sure that you always match triplets:

```
re.findall("ATG(?:.{3})*?(?:TA[AG]|TGA)", s)
```

Comment: Just to add, if you were interested in only the parts in between, change the expression into a _capture group_, `re.findall('START(.*?)END',s)` will give you `['FFFP', 'DOINVOIJHSDF']` as the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
a="FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDC"
a[a.find('START'):]


'STARTFFFPENDDCDC'
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way (no loop, no regex):

```
s = "FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDC"
tmp = s[s.find("START") + len("START"):]
result = tmp[:tmp.find("END")]
```

Comment: What if there were different end values? In other words, instead of just ending with "END", the values "DONE" and "NOMORE" would also end it? And in addition to that, there were multiple starts and ends throughout the string. For example:

"STARTFFEFFDONEFEWFSTARTFEFFENDDDW"

Comment: If you need DONE and NOMORE replace START and END with them in the code above. If there are multiple START-END clauses, you need a loop or regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourString = 'FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDC'
substring = yourString[yourString.find("START") + len("START") : yourString.find("END")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that efficient but does work.

```
>>> s = "FEFEWFSTARTFFFPENDDCDC"
>>> s[s.index('START'):s.index('END')+len('END')]
'STARTFFFPEND'
```